# Module not found when running scrapy in celery

Tags: python, scrapy, multiprocessing, celery

EDIT: I found out it only happened on a Windows computer. Everything works fine on Linux server.

I am running a scrapy crawler in a celery process and keep getting this error. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

```
[2021-08-18 11:28:42,294: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to sqla+sqlite:///celerydb.sqlite
[2021-08-18 11:28:42,313: INFO/MainProcess] celery@NP45086 ready.    
[2021-08-18 09:46:58,330: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: app_celery.scraping_process_cli[e94dc192-e10e-4921-ad0c-bb932be9b568]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Program Files\Python374\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
        exitcode = _main(fd)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python374\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
        self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app_celery'
    [2021-08-18 09:46:58,773: INFO/MainProcess] Task app_celery.scraping_process_cli[e94dc192-e10e-4921-ad0c-bb932be9b568] succeeded in 0.4380000000091968s: None
```

My app_celery looks like this:

```
app = Celery('app_celery', backend=..., broker=...)

def scrape_data():
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    crawler = process.create_crawler(spider_cls)
    process.crawl(spider_cls, **kwargs)
    process.start()

@app.task(name='app_celery.scraping_process_cli', time_limit=1200, max_retries=3)
def scraping_process_cli(company_id):
    import multiprocessing
    a = multiprocessing.Process(target=scrape_data())
    a.start()
    a.join()
```

I am running the celery as:

```
celery -A app_celery worker -c 4 -n worker1 --pool threads
```

Comment: Celery predates multiprocessing. They have their own process control package called billiard that you should use when you need to create processes for an example. Project link: https://github.com/celery/billiard . For the record, I am not saying this is the reason for the ModuleNotFoundError . That typically happens when your PYTHONPATH is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. Before do step 2, change directory to the project root of your scrapy project.
2. You have to tell `CrawlerProcess()` to load `settings.py`.

```py
import os

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


def scrape_data():
    os.chdir("/path/to/your/scrapy/project_root")
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    process.crawl('spider_name')
    process.start()
```

Comment: I forgot the settings in my question. Anyway, I tried changing the directory like you wrote and I still get the same error.

Comment: @iam.mattevans How did you run command `celery -A app_celery`. Were you in the dir where `app_celery` is?  Seems the problem is failing to start celery but not internal scrapy app.

Comment: I am running it from the same directory. The celery starts up normally, it even logs that it received the task, so celery must be working fine. When instead of `multiprocessing.Process(target=scrape_data())` I write `multiprocessing.Process(target=print("hello")`, everything runs perfectly fine.